# How to show that $d(z_n, \mathbb C \setminus G) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty\ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a region. Let there be an $R \gt 0$ such that $\{z\ |\ |z| \gt R\} \subseteq G.$ Let $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be an infinite sequence in $G$ with no terms being repeated infinitely many times. If $|z_j| \leq R$ for all $j \geq 1$ and the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ has no limit point in $G$ then show that $d(z_n, \mathbb C \setminus G) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

Since $G$ is open and contains the complement of a ball it follows that $\mathbb C \setminus G$ is closed and bounded and hence compact. Also $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence of infinitely many terms and hence it has a limit point. But according to the hypothesis no limit point can lie in $G$ and therefore they have to be in $\mathbb C \setminus G$ which in particular implies that $\mathbb C \setminus G \neq \varnothing.$ So $\mathbb C \setminus G$ is a non-empty compact subset of the complex plane. So there exists $w_n \in \mathbb C \setminus G$ such that for all $n \geq 1$ $$|z_n - w_n| = d(z_n, \mathbb C \setminus G).$$ So we need only to show that $|z_n - w_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$ Let $\ell \in \mathbb C \setminus G$ be a limit point of $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}.$ Then for any given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ we have $|z_n - \ell| \lt \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n.$ But since $|z_n - w_n| \leq |z_n - \ell|$ for all $n \geq 1$ it follows that $|z_n - w_n| \lt \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n.$ Now I got stuck and couldn't proceed further. From here I can't conclude that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $|z_n - w_n| \lt \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n)$ in $\mathbb C \setminus G$ then there is a subsequence $(z_{n_k})$ converging to $z$. This implies $d(z_{n_k},\mathbb C \setminus G) \leq d(z_{n_k},z)\to 0$.

Now any subsequence of $(z_n)$ also satisfies the hypothesis and we can use our argument to the subsequence. So we can conclude that any subsequence of $d(z_n,\mathbb C \setminus G)$ has a further subsequnce which tends to $0$. This implies that the entire sequence tends to $0$.